# slf4j - logback NullPointer in Spring MVC tests

Tags: java, spring, logback, slf4j

I am running some unit tests and I was to use SLF4J and logback.

Here is the relevant pom.xml

```
     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6-RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.7</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

And here is the log and stacktrace:

```
20:29:16,293 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback-test.xml] at [file:/code/web/target/test-classes/logback-test.xml]
20:29:16,387 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder@7a1ebcd8 - Unexpected exception while parsing XML document. java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.NullPointerException
at  at org.xml.sax.helpers.LocatorImpl.<init>(LocatorImpl.java:103)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEvent.<init>(SaxEvent.java:31)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.StartEvent.<init>(StartEvent.java:27)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.startElement(SaxEventRecorder.java:106)
at  at org.allcolor.xml.parser.CShaniSaxParser.parseStartTag(CShaniSaxParser.java:1393)
at  at org.allcolor.xml.parser.CXmlParser.parseSTARTTag(CXmlParser.java:1405)
at  at org.allcolor.xml.parser.CXmlParser.parse(CXmlParser.java:682)
at  at org.allcolor.xml.parser.CShaniSaxParser.parse(CShaniSaxParser.java:767)
at  at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:392)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.recordEvents(SaxEventRecorder.java:59)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:141)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:103)
at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
at  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
at  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
at  at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
at  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<clinit>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:91)
at  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at  at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
```

And the logback-test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>.%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg %n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>TRACE</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    </root> 
    <logger name="com.me.ControllerTester" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

Now I have checked the dependency tree, and I have nothing conflicting.  I have tried messing with the SAX parser versions.

The XML looks fine to me.  I must be conflicted somehow...

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`logback` uses [`SAXParserFactory.newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html#newInstance()), which has a lookup procedure that determines which implementation to use. It seems that `org.allcolor.xml.parser.CShaniSaxParser` is being selected in your environment based on this lookup:

> `public static SAXParserFactory newInstance()`
>
> Obtain a new instance of a `SAXParserFactory`. This static method creates a new factory instance This method uses the following ordered lookup procedure to determine the `SAXParserFactory` implementation class to load:
>
> - Use the `javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory` system property.
> - Use the properties file "lib/jaxp.properties" in the JRE directory. This configuration file is in standard `java.util.Properties` format and contains the fully qualified name of the implementation class with the key being the system property defined above. The jaxp.properties file is read only once by the JAXP implementation and it's values are then cached for future use. If the file does not exist when the first attempt is made to read from it, no further attempts are made to check for its existence. It is not possible to change the value of any property in jaxp.properties after it has been read for the first time.
> - Use the Services API (as detailed in the JAR specification), if available, to determine the classname. The Services API will look for a classname in the file `META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory` in jars available to the runtime.
> - Platform default `SAXParserFactory` instance.
>
> Once an application has obtained a reference to a `SAXParserFactory` it can use the factory to configure and obtain parser instances.
>
> #### Tip for Trouble-shooting
>
> Setting the `jaxp.debug` system property will cause this method to print a lot of debug messages to System.err about what it is doing and where it is looking at.
>
> If you have problems loading `DocumentBuilders`, try:
>
> `java -Djaxp.debug=1 YourProgram ....`

Try switching to a standard SAX parser (such as [Apache Xerces](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/apache/xerces/jaxp/SAXParserFactoryImpl.html)) by setting `javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory` system property for your unit tests:

```
-Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
```

Comment: I set it up in the jaxp.properties, and it all works great now.  Thanks!